# How to disable ipython's annoying error messages

Tags: python-3.x, ipython

Every time that I run a python script using `python3 script.py`, when script encounters a problem python prints out a bunch of lines, some related to Ipython3:

```
Traceback
....
....
....
# <--- THIS PART --->
If you suspect this is an IPython bug, please report it at:
    https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues
or send an email to the mailing list at ipython-dev@python.org

You can print a more detailed traceback right now with "%tb", or use "%debug"
to interactively debug it.

Extra-detailed tracebacks for bug-reporting purposes can be enabled via:
    %config Application.verbose_crash=True
# <--- THIS PART --->
```

Is there anyway to disable it so I can easily look at the traceback?

Comment: I opened an issue on Github: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/12139 . Those messages really are annoying.

Comment: Any updates/insights on this?